# Call a function with variadic arguments using parameter pack expansion, but modify th i-th parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

Suppose we have a function

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
T f(Args... args);
```

and we want to call `f` in an other function

```
template<typename... Args>
void bar(Args... args) {
    // f(args1, ..., args(i-1), "modified argsi", args(i+1), ..., argsn);
}
```

and modify the `i`-th argument (and leave the other arguments untouched) for all `i = 1, ..., n`. `f` will return a result and I want to store all `n` results in a `valarray`.

How can we do that?

Comment: Is `i` known at compile time or only at runtime?

Comment: @0xbadf00d You didn't answer that question - compile time or runtime? Where does `i` come from?

Comment: but the whole point of variadic template is that number does not mean anything. it can have anything from 0 to infinity arguments.. what happens if n is actually smaller then i ?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Uh. What? So you want to call `f` with all of the `args...` modified, where does the `T` come from then? And what do you want to do with the result of `f()`?

Comment: @Barry Actually, I answer the question. We know `n = sizeof...(args)`. And I need to call f with modified i-th argument, for all i = 1, ..., n

Comment: @Barry Sorry, I didn't want to write, what I'd written.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Do you want to modify **all** the arguments, yes or no?

Answer (score 3):

With `I` a compile time value, you may do:

```
namespace detail
{

    template<std::size_t I>
    struct impl
    {
        template <typename TUPLE>
        auto operator() (TUPLE&& t) { return std::get<I>(t); }
    };

    template<>
    struct impl<2>
    {
        template <typename TUPLE>
        auto operator() (TUPLE&& t) { return std::get<2>(t) + 40; }
    };

    template <std::size_t... Is, typename TUPLE>
    void bar(std::index_sequence<Is...>, TUPLE&& Tuple) {
        return f(impl<Is>{}(std::forward<TUPLE>(Tuple))...);
    }

}

template<typename... Args>
void bar(Args... args) {
    detail::bar(std::index_sequence_for<Args...>(), std::forward_as_tuple(args...));
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/HkLiKM)

With `i` a runtime value:

```
namespace detail
{

    template<class T>
    auto modifier(T&& arg, std::size_t i, std::size_t pos) {
        if (i == pos)
            return arg + 40; // Or appropriate modification.
        else
            return std::forward<T>(arg);
    }

    template <std::size_t... Is, typename... Args>
    void bar(std::size_t pos, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Args&&... args) {
        return f(modifier(std::forward<Args>(args), Is, pos)...);
    }

}

template<typename... Args>
void bar(std::size_t pos, Args&&... args) {
    detail::bar(pos, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>(), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/14EHgs)

Comment: You can also use a ternary operator instead of the additional function + if-clause. Not sure if it's easier to read: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a97dd83b3b070f36

Answer (score 1):

Well, a lookup table does the job, if branching is to be avoided. Rough sketch:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

void foo(std::string a, std::string b, std::string c) {
    std::cout << a << '|' << b << '|' << c;
}

template <typename, typename> struct passerAux;
template <std::size_t... prevI, std::size_t... followI>
struct passerAux<std::index_sequence<prevI...>, std::index_sequence<followI...>> {
    template <typename... Args>
    static decltype(auto) passer( Args&&... args ) {
        auto tuple = std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return foo( std::forward<std::tuple_element_t<prevI, decltype(tuple)>>(std::get<prevI>(tuple))...,
                    "ModifiedArg",
                    std::forward<std::tuple_element_t<followI+sizeof...(prevI)+1, decltype(tuple)>>(std::get<followI+sizeof...(prevI)+1>(tuple))... );
    }
};

template <typename... Args, std::size_t... indices>
decltype(auto) passer( std::size_t i, std::index_sequence<indices...>, Args&&... args ) {
    void(*lookup[])(Args&&...) {
        passerAux<std::make_index_sequence<indices>, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)-indices-1>>::passer...
    };
    return lookup[i](std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename... Args>
decltype(auto) passer( std::size_t i, Args&&... args ) {
    return passer(i, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{}, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
}

int main() {
    passer(0, "A", "B", "C"); std::cout << '\n';
    passer(1, "A", "B", "C"); std::cout << '\n';
    passer(2, "A", "B", "C");
}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35770a0ce6db0687).

Comment: `void(*lookup[])(Args&&...)` My eyes! D:

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I think (?) you want something like:

```
namespace detail {
    template <typename Arg, typename Idx>
    auto modify_arg(Arg&& arg, Idx )
    {
        // TODO: whatever modifications you want to make
        // to the argument indexed by Idx
    }

    template <size_t... Is, typename... Args>
    void bar(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Args&&... args) 
    {
        // Don't know where 'T' comes from - you still
        // need that for your f()
        f(modify_arg(std::forward<Args>(args),
                     std::integral_constant<size_t, Is>{})...
                     );
    }
}

template<typename... Args>
void bar(Args&&... args) {
    detail::bar(std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{},
                std::forward<Args>(args)...
                );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A non compile time implementation might be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// Replace a value at a position
// =============================

template<typename R>
struct Replace {
    int i;
    R replacement;
    Replace(int i, R&& replacement)
    :   i(i), replacement(replacement)
    {}

    template<typename T>
    T&& operator() (T&& value) noexcept {
        return (0 == i--)
            ? std::forward<T>(replacement)
            : std::forward<T>(value);
    }
};

template <typename R, typename... Args>
Replace<R> replace(int i, R&& replacement) {
    return Replace<R>(i, std::forward<R>(replacement));
}

// Test: Print values
// ==================

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void print(const T&, const Args&...);

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void print(const T& value) {
    std::cout << value << '\n';
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void print(const T& value, const Args&... args) {
    std::cout << value << '\n';
    print(args...);
}


// Test: Function
// ==============

template<typename... Args>
void f(Args... args) {
    // Note, 'print(replace(1, 7)(args)...);' will not work.
    auto r = replace(1, 7);
    print(r(args)...);
}


int main()
{
    f(1, 2, 3);
}
```